# Signals not working as intended (C language, linux)

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

I tried to answer this question:

> Write a program C that creates two children. The second child process
> is blocked until the reception of the signal SIGUSR1 sent from the
> parent process. While the first child process is blocked until the
> reception of the signal SIGUSR2 (that will kill him) sent from the
> second child process. The parent is terminated after the termination
> of his children.

However the execution is not working as intended with my code below, and only the parent `printf`s are displayed. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

My code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

void this(int sig) {
    printf("this is this");
}

int main() {
    int pid = fork();
    int pid2;

    if (pid < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("FIrst child is paused");
        pause();
        printf("ERror");
    } else {
        pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 < 0) {
            exit(-2);
        } else if (pid2 == 0) {
            signal(SIGUSR1, &this);
            printf("Second child is paused");
            pause();
            kill(pid,SIGUSR2);
            printf("signal sent to first child");
        } else {
            printf("this is the parent");
            kill(pid2, SIGUSR1);
            printf("signal sent to second child");
            wait(NULL);
            exit(-3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add newline characters at the end of all of your printfs, e.g. `printf("hello\n");`. See the `\n`, that's the newline character.

Comment: It is not safe to call `printf` from a signal handler, and is a bad habit to do so.  For simple toy problems like this it is not likely to cause a problem, but you should not do it.  There is a relatively short list of things that are safe in a signal handler, and best practice is to do as little as possible.  Generally, just set a global sig_atomic_t  and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You make no provision to ensure that the parent's signal is delivered to the second child only when that child is ready for it.  Because process startup takes some time, chances are good that the signal is indeed delivered sooner.  In that case, the second child will be terminated (default disposition of `SIGUSR1`) or it will block indefinitely in `pause()` (if the signal is received after the handler is installed but before `pause`ing).  In neither case will the second child signal the first.

Signal masks and signal dispositions are inherited across a fork, so you can address that by blocking `SIGUSR1` in the parent before forking, and then using `sigsuspend()` in the child instead of `pause()`, which will enable you to *atomically* unblock the signal and start waiting for it.

The same is not an issue for the first child because you're looking for it to exercise the default disposition for `SIGUSR2` (termination), and it does not matter for the specified behavior whether that happens before that child reaches or blocks in `pause()`.

---

Additionally,

- the parent waits only for one child, but the prompt seems to say that it must wait for *both*.  Perhaps you dropped the second `wait()` because the parent was not terminating, but if so, that was a missed clue that one of the children was not terminating.
- `printf` is not async-signal-safe, so calling it from a signal handler invokes undefined behavior.
- you should put a newline at the end of your `printf` formats.  This will make your output much more readable, and it will also ensure that the output is delivered to the screen promptly.  That could end up being useful as you debug.  Alternatively, use `puts()` instead of `printf()` since you are outputting only fixed strings.  `puts()` will add a newline automatically.

  The absence of newlines probably explains why the first child's output from before it `pause`s is never printed.  If the second child were reaching the indefinite `pause` state then it would also explain why that child's pre-`pause` output was not being printed.